I'm using SSIS in ADF to move .csv from a blob container to another and then ingest into a Azure SQL database. I get an assembly error
I'm receiving the below error...
Copy Files To Working Area: Error: Could not load file or asembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common.Version=11.1.3.0 Culture=neutral. PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
The above error occurs when running the SSIS package from within ADF. When I run in the SSIS package on the VM the data passes into the Azure-SQL-DB nicely.
We are moving away from the VM and so this is our first foray into using Data Factory for SSIS packages. I get the feeling there is a parameter/file/variable which is stored on the VM which we haven't either setup or specified in ADF, however, I'm not sure and googling hasn't yet got me to the answer.

Add your pipeline configuration done in adf.

Don't use ADF and just re-build everything in Fabric was the answer.
